# Dataproc: functools.partial no attribute '__module__' error for pyspark UDF

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, google-cloud-dataproc, functools

I am using GCP/Dataproc for some spark/graphframe calculations.

In my private spark/hadoop standalone cluster, 
I have no issue using `functools.partial` when defining pysparkUDF.

But, now with GCP/Dataproc, I have an issue as below.

Here are some basic settings to check whether `partial` works well or not.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from functools import partial

def power(base, exponent):
    return base ** exponent
```

In the main function, `functools.partial` works well in ordinary cases as we expect:

```
# see whether partial works as it is
square = partial(power, exponent=2)
print "*** Partial test = ", square(2)
```

But, if I put this `partial(power, exponent=2)` function to PySparkUDF as below,

```
testSquareUDF = F.udf(partial(power, exponent=2),T.FloatType())    
testdf = inputdf.withColumn('pxsquare',testSquareUDF('px'))
```

I have this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/bf297080f57a457dba4d3b347ed53ef0/gcloudtest-partial-error.py", line 120, in <module>
    testSquareUDF = F.udf(square,T.FloatType())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1971, in udf
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1955, in _udf
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))

AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'

ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.pyspark) Job [bf297080f57a457dba4d3b347ed53ef0] entered state [ERROR] while waiting for [DONE].
```

=========

I had no this kind of issue with my standalone cluster. 
My spark cluster version is 2.1.1. 
The GCP dataproc's is 2.2.x

Anyone can recognize what prevents me from passing the `partial` function to the UDF?

Comment: I have found that **spark 2.2** has some issue on passing `functools.partial` to UDF. This was fixed with the release of **spark 2.3**. So, avoiding 2.2 if you use `partial` a lot.

Comment: FYI Dataproc supports Spark 2.3 as well: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions. Just pass `--image-version=1.3` when creating your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21432) was with spark 2.2. And, since spark 2.3 is also [supported by Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions), just using `--image-version=1.3` when creating the cluster fixes it.